# I am trying to make a checkerboard

Tags: python

I am trying to make a checkerboard, using the variable color_value, and using the modulus operator to determine whether the square should be red or black. I am unsure of how to use the modulus operator.

```
speed(0)
penup()
setposition(-200,-200)
pendown()
color_value = 0

def red_square():
    color("red")
    for i in range(4):
        forward(40)
        left(90)
def black_square():
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        forward(40)
        left(90)

def make_squares():
    for i in range(2):
        if color_value / 2 == 0:
            begin_fill()
            red_square()
            end_fill()
        elif color_value / 2 != 0:
            black_square()
        color_value+1
        penup()
        forward(40)
        pendown()
            

make_squares()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where or why you are trying to use the modulus operator, but to answer your question more broadly on how to use the modulus operator, the modulus operator `%` is put between two numbers and the expression returns the remainder when the first number is divided by the second number. For example:

```
3 % 2   # Returns 1 because 1 is the remainder when 3 is divided by 2
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the modulus operator in my if statement, as in, if the color_value % 2 ==0 for instance, that would make the square either red or black depending on what the remainder of the color_value

Comment: @IcoSli Just change the `/` to a `%` in `if colour_value / 2 == 0`

Comment: I changed that, but when I ran the code it made only red squares.

Comment: @IcoSli Ok, I have updated my answer, there is a full code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
n % k == 0
```

Evaluates true if and only if `n` is an exact multiple of `k`. In elementary maths this is known as the remainder from a division.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `if color_value / 2 == 0` into `if color_value % 2 == 0`

And change `color_value+1` into `color_value+=1`

And make sure your squares don't overlap

## Here is the full code for you

```
    speed(0)
    penup()
    setposition(-200,-200)
    pendown()
    color_value = 0
    
    def red_square():
        color("red")
        for i in range(4):
            forward(40)
            left(90)
    def black_square():
        begin_fill()
        for i in range(4):
            forward(40)
            right(90)
    
    def make_squares():
        for i in range(2):
            if color_value % 2 == 0:
                begin_fill()
                red_square()
                end_fill()
            elif color_value % 2 != 0:
                black_square()
            color_value+=1
            penup()
            forward(40)
            pendown()
                
    
    make_squares()
```